# Larger HTML files VS client templating

Tags: javascript, html, templates, web

Let's assume i have 50 views in my app, all of these views include user html.

```
<div>Hi, im a user</div>
```

What would be faster, loading and rendering the user view in the client and using the template engine to attach it to all of the other 50 views OR if this piece of HTML were on each of the 50 views, making their files larger, but eliminating the need for client rendering and the additional Http request?

**Edit**

I'm not concerned about duplicate code, we will compile the small piece of code, so it won't be duplicated. The question is strictly about speed of larger HTML files VS client rendering + http request.

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid putting the same exact HTML in every file. **Use includes/templating/partials in order to display headers/footers so that when you need to make a change, you only need to change one file. Not 50.**

As far as loading parts of the page asynch; It's all about what you want the loading to look like to the client. Asynch loading appears faster to the end user because the initial page load is faster (less data to transmit) but actually takes longer over all because of the multiple http requests.

Comment: Perhaps i wasn't clear enough, please see my edit :-)

Comment: So you are wondering about loading the user view asynchronously using javascript?

Comment: No, i wondering what will be faster: if the user view was hardcoded into every other view, or if it will be attached by include/as a partial. So large HTML files VS client templating/loading via http.

Comment: Right, but the client loading would be ajax is what I was asking. It's all about what you want the loading to look like to the client. Asynch loading appears faster to the end user because the initial page load is faster (less data to transmit) but actually takes longer over time.